# Table \rowcolor \multicolumn color displacement

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn, rowcolor

I have the following table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\pagestyle{plain} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{YY}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
\multicolumn{2}{C{\textwidth}}{Patologie Comunemente Trattate con Trapianto Allogenico di Cellule Staminali Ematopoietiche} \\ \hline
Neoplasie & Altre Patologie\\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
Leucemia Mieloide Acuta & Anemia Aplastica \\ 
Leucemia Linfoblastica Acuta & Emoglobinuria Parossistica Notturna \\ 
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
Leucemia Mieloide Cronica & Anemia di Fanconi \\ 
Sindromi Mielodisplastiche & Anemia di Blackfan–Diamond \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
Disordini Mieloproliferativi & Thalassemia Major \\ 
Linfomi Non-Hodgkin & Anemia Falciforme \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
Malattia di Hodgkin & Immunodeficienza Severa Combinata \\ 
Leucemia Linfocitica Cronica & Sindrome di Wiskott–Aldrich \\ 
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
Mieloma Multiplo & Linfoistiocitosi Emofagocitica\\ 
Leucemia Mieloide Cronica Giovanile & Errori Congeniti del Metabolismo \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Indicazioni al Trapianto Allogenico. Tratto da Copelan, The New England Journal of Medicine, 2006.}
\label{TabellaIndicazioni}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It uses `\rowcolor`, and `\multicolumn` to provide a colored header, like this:

### [image]

How can I avoid the header color displacement on the top right corner?

Thank you very much for any advice.

Comment: please fix your example so that people can run it to see the problem, and test possible answers. So far all we know is you use non standard column types such as Y and C and perhaps one of them has an error somewhere

Comment: most likely the error is `C{\textwidth}` where that length is too wide and should perhaps be `C{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}` to allow for the cell padding but that can only be a guess without knowing how `C` is defined.

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle! The error was exactly the `C{\textwidth}` one! Sorry for the poor details in the question. I will include the `\usepackage` as well so can be more clear the environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is `C{\textwidth}` where that length is too wide and should  be `C{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}` to allow for the cell padding of `\tabcolsep` either side of the entry.